# Not able to ssh my aws ec2 instance which contains my wordpress files

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have configured my ec2 instances three days back and installed wordpress and added my files in the instances. Suddenly, from last night my ec2 public ip is showing timeout when I try to open the link in
browser.

My security setting are open for all traffic , I didn't change any modifications to the default settings has when creating instance. Not sure what to do , request some one help to sort it out.

Comment: Are you using the public IP address of the instance or maybe you were using some sort of static ip, which iirc refreshes in 24 hours or something.

Comment: Are you using an elastic IP with your instance? If not the IP is not static and therefore can be lost.

Comment: Link in browser or ssh?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams no i am not using elastic ip

Comment: @Perimosh both not working which was working till yesterday afternoon

Comment: @Hiro I am using Public DNS (IPv4) provided in description tab of my instance

Comment: @Karthik in your setup Elastic IP is kind of a must-have. One more factor is the instance type because sometimes the underlying hypervisor has issues and AWS tries to move the instance and that changes the IP address of the instance. If you use Elastic IP, you are safe from that. Be careful with the security settings where you mentioned it is open for all traffic. Try to put this instance behind a load balancer and have only the HTTP/HTTPS port open. There are too many things to take care of, these are just minimum.

Comment: @samtoddler If i create a elastic ip and hook to my instance which is down now. Will I be possible to ssh the instance with the elastic ip?

Comment: down in the sense?,  that depends on your instance state as well, check what it is in? get the current public IP of the instance and try ssh'ing into it, [check the instance logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html)

Comment: my instance is in running state but issue is neither I am not able to view my site using public ip through browser or even ssh. If I create a elastic ip for instance where I am not able to ssh , will I be able to ssh using elastic ip?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to spin up and provision a new EC2 instance with wordpress on it, then attach and mount your old EBS volume (from your old EC2 instance) to the new EC2 instance.

Just in case something bad happen, always [create EBS snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html) first.

See this docs for [detaching an Amazon EBS volume from a Linux instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-detaching-volume.html), and this docs for [attaching an Amazon EBS volume to an instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html).

Comment: is there any way to sort out the issue in the current instance?

Comment: You can try to access the EC2 instance by using [Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#start-ec2-console) instead of SSH.

Answer (score 0):

As you're not using an [elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) for your instance, you should attach one so that the IP address cannot change in the future (even if the instance restarts or shuts down).

Once you've done this you will need to resolve and DNS records to this new IP address and use this IP address in the browser. However this will not need to be done again in he future, and you will maintain the same instance.

Also double check that your security groups are not bound to any specific IP addresses for an inbound rule, if your IP address is not fixed. If they are then either update them to your current IP or consider another ingress method to access if it is internal to your organisation.

Comment: So if I have one elastic ip address , and hook to my instance for which I am not able to ssh then is it possible for me to ssh the instance using elastic ip?

Comment: Yes as long as your instance is publicly accessible, with ingress access from your IP